# MDC snackbar overlapping with alert popup when both comes same time ios 13

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11

[Here it is , This is how it looks when both comes together , else whever only snackbar comes it is shown at bottom as intended.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wwIu.png)

Code for snackBar

```
 class func showSnackBar(stringMessage:String,bottomHeight:CGFloat) {
        let message = MDCSnackbarMessage()
        message.text = stringMessage
    
        MDCSnackbarManager.messageTextColor = .white
        MDCSnackbarManager.snackbarMessageViewBackgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        MDCSnackbarManager.show(message)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            MDCSnackbarManager.setBottomOffset(bottomHeight)
        }
        
        //MDCSnackbarMessageView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints(<#T##UIView#>)
    }
```

This is coming on device as well as simulator , pod file use for snackbar genration is
pod 'MaterialComponents/Snackbar’
pod 'MaterialComponents/Snackbar+ColorThemer'

and This is the code for alert which is shown behind the snackbar

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let alertController = UIAlertController (title: NSLocalizedString("Allow \"Club Apparel\" to access your location?", comment: ""), message: NSLocalizedString("We will use the device location services to help you find stores and serve relevant content.", comment: ""), preferredStyle: .alert)
                    
                    
                    let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Settings", comment: ""), style: .default) { (_) -> Void in
                        
                        guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) else {
                            return
                        }
                        
                        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
                            UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
                                print("Settings opened: \(success)") // Prints true
                            })
                        }
                    }
                    alertController.addAction(settingsAction)
                    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: ""), style: .default, handler: nil)
                    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
                    
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `presentationHostView`

Use the following code

```
if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate, let window = appDelegate.window {
    MDCSnackbarManager.shared.setPresentationHostView(window)
}
```